# Cannot load mod_xml2enc Apache2 module

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, reverse-proxy

I'm installing reverse-proxy-related modules to Apache2 HTTPserver but `mod_xml2enc` module isn't found in module directory.

How can I install in *(Red Hat 4.4.7-23)* with Apache/2.2.15

I'm having the previous error occur returning `libxml2.so` "not found".  Is it resolved by using `/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2`?

Answer (score 2):

1. First download the libxml2 using

   ```
   sudo yum install libxml2-devel
   ```
2. Install the Apache Extension tools using

   ```
   yum install httpd-devel
   ```
3. download the [mod_xml2enc.c](http://apache.webthing.com/svn/apache/filters/mod_xml2enc.c) and [mod_xml2enc.h](http://apache.webthing.com/svn/apache/filters/mod_xml2enc.h)
4. place it any directory and run below command in that directory.

   ```
   apps -i -a -c -I /usr/include/libxml2/ mod_xml2enc.c
   ```
5. download [mod_proxy_html.c](http://apache.webthing.com/svn/apache/filters/mod_proxy_html.c)
6. place it any directory and run below command in that directory

   ```
   apxs -c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I. -i mod_xml2enc.c
   ```

Comment: I would recommend going with `xml2-config --cflags --libs` as a more standard method to find the proper linkage and flags.